# Strong Name Validation Failed. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8013141A)

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am encountering this error when I am trying to create a new Integration Service Project from Visual Studio 2022. I am using Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2022 (V-17.8.1).